# `shutil.copyfile` Error: Permissions Denied

Tags: python, shutil, file-copying

I have worked through a number of other threads on this, but not of their solutions seem to work here, that or I am not understanding properly, and would love your help.

I am getting a:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'W:\\test\\Temporary Folder 195\\Sub-fold1
```

This is the general code i started with.

```
    summary_file = r'W:/test/SDC Analysis Summary.docm'
    shutil.copyfile(summary_file, os.getcwd())
```

I have also varied this a little bit based on other threads, specifically replacing summary_file with the actual text and also adding \ to the end of working directory without success. Really don't know what I'm missing here. I know that the Documentation is looking for complete paths, but I believe I am satisfying that requirement. What am I missing here?

Note: there is a desire to use copyfile over copy due to the speed increase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html):

```
 dst must be the complete target file name
```

You can't just use `os.getcwd()` as the destination.

Comment: why not, doesnt os.getcwd() get the complete target file path>?

Comment: @WolVes: The docs don't say *target file PATH*. They say *target file NAME*.

Comment: It's a directory name.  You need to give the filename as well: `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "SDC Analysis Summary.docm")`, for example.

Comment: O.o gotcha. Thanks Eduffy!

Answer (score 0):

you should be the complete target file name for destination

destination = pathdirectory + filename.*

I use this code fir copy wav file with shutil :

```
    # open file with QFileDialog

    browse_file = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open file', 'c:', "wav files (*.wav)")

    # get file name 

    base = os.path.basename(browse_file[0])
    os.path.splitext(base)
    print(os.path.splitext(base)[1])

    # make destination path with file name

    destination= "test/" + os.path.splitext(base)[0] + os.path.splitext(base)[1]
    shutil.copyfile(browse_file[0], destination)
```